# Putting multiple arrays from GetValueNames() into one array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, registry

I have a method that needs to create an array that holds the names of the subkeys of a root key, and then I need another array that will hold the values within all of those subkeys. My predicament is how do I create a multidimensional array that holds multiple arrays within it?

My code thus far:

```
    private void registryArrays() {

        //Two string arrays for holding subkeys and values
        string[] subKeys;
        string[] values = new string[];

        //reg key is used to access the root key CurrentUsers
        RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        RegistryKey regSubKey;

        //Assign all subkey names from the currentusers root key
        subKeys = regKey.GetSubKeyNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < subKeys.Length; i++) {

            regSubKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(subKeys[i]);
            values[i] = regSubKey.GetValueNames();

        }
    }
```

I am at a loss as to how to go about this since GetValueNames() will give me an array, but I need to get multiple arrays as the for loop will iterate through my root key's subkeys, so how will I put all the arrays into one array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multiple arrays. Using a dictionary could be better. For ex;

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
var console = regKey.OpenSubKey("Console");
var dict = console.GetValueNames()
          .ToDictionary(key => key, key => console.GetValue(key));


foreach (var kv in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value);
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this but ToDictionary does not work with arrays. Or at least that is the issue I am getting.

Comment: @JBeck Just copy/paste above example and try, after that, if you have a *specific problem* other than *"doesn't work"* (which doesn't give any info to me), I may try to answer it.

Comment: Okay after some tweaking to the code you gave me using a dictionary was definitely a better approach. I appreciate the help!